# Python print() output discrepancy

Tags: python, printing, concatenation

I'm messing around with python, following this tutorial:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Hello,_World

According to it, my output for the following code:

```
print("Single String")
print("Concat", "String")
```

Should look like this:

```
Single String
Concat String
```

But it looks like this:

```
Single String
('Concat', 'String')
```

Why is this? I'm on OSX with Python 2.6.

EDIT: I just realized the guide is for 3.0, and I have 2.6. Is that causing the issue? What is the quickest way to upgrade my Python install?

EDIT 2: An upgrade fixed it :) Accepted answer explains the differences.

Comment: Regarding the upgrade: If you are happy with Python 2.6, then there's nothing to upgrade, just use the Python 2.x syntax.

Comment: Well I've only used python for 20mins ever, so I'd rather use the newest for learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print("Concat", "String")
```

This is a `tuple`. When you put the `,` it becomes a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and hence Python outputs it the same way.

```
>>> t = ('Let', 'Us', 'Test')
>>> type(t)
<type 'tuple'>
```

A tuple consists of a number of values separated by commas.

Comment: Also note that `print("Single string",)` will also output the tuple.

Comment: What could I do to get the behavior I expect to get? And for that matter, on things being strange, why does: print(22 / 7) output 3? Shouldn't it only do that if I use // instead of / ?

Comment: @Josh `print "concat", "string"`. And for the second question, it changed from python 2.x to 3. In python 2.x,  `//` is added just for developers to accommodate with it.

Comment: `22/7`, both are integers here so Python outputs it as 3. `//` is floor division. If you want `22/7` to be equal to `3.1428571428571428`, do a `from __future__ import division`. This behaviour has been changed in Python 3, where 22/7 defaults to 3.1428571428571428 only.

Answer (score 2):

*Not an answer to the OP's original question, which I think sukhbir answered quite well, but to the follow up question.*

I believe the quickest way to upgrade would be to go to the [Python website](http://www.python.org/download/) and download v3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2.x you can just use

```
print "Single", "String"
```

Python 3.x changes the way print works, previously it was a statement and now it is a function.

Comment: Ah! So once my upgrade from 2.6 to 3.1.3 is done, I can use print("A","B") as I'd expect?

Answer (score 2):

For compatibility in `Python 2.7` you can use placeholders

```
print('%s %s')%("Concat", "String")
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are running a Python 3 tutorial with Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.6 you can also say

```
from __future__ import print_statement
```

to get the 3.x syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To get the behaviour you want, you need to print a string representation of the tuple. You can get this by using the `join` method on strings:

```
print ' '.join(('a', 'b'))
```

The reason the behaviour is not as expected is that in Python 2, `print` is a keyword. In Python 3, it has been replaced by a function (also `print`), so the latter syntax calls the function instead of printing a tuple. You can replicate the behaviour you have see in Python 3 with

```
print(('a', 'b'))
```

One set of parentheses for the function call, and one for the tuple.

Comment: I think you meant `print` is a statement in Python 2.x, but in Python 3 it is a function. It is a keyword alright, but here the comparison is between a statement and a function.